std::sort compare function caueses a heap-buffer-overflow
I wrote the following compare function for sorting:
bool cmp(int a, int b) {
    return a % 2 == 0;
}

Let the even number be in front of the odd number, and you will get AC in a small test case but a heap-buffer-overflow in a larger case.
But when I changed to:
bool cmp(int a, int b) {
    return a % 2 == 0 && b % 2 == 1;
}

It works perfectly.
I wonder what's different between them in this problem. This problem is in leetcode, and the link is following.
https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-array-by-parity/description/
and this is my full code of this problem
// bool cmp(int a, int b) {
//     return a % 2 == 0;
// }//wrong method

// bool cmp(int a, int b) {
//     return a % 2 == 0 && b % 2 == 1;
// }//AC method
class Solution {
    public:
        vector<int> sortArrayByParity(vector<int>& nums) {
            sort(nums.begin(),nums.end(),cmp);
            return nums;
        }
};

I think both functions can meet the requirements of the question. I want to know why there is such a difference.

I'm not sure whether the bad comparator is specifically undefined behavior, its still wrong though as there are values for which a < b && b < a is true. Also, you're probably looking for std::partition.

For such a simple predicate, you may wish to avoid the cmp function altogether and just use a lambda.

Welcome to StackOverflow @LouieK. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Your first comparator:
bool cmp(int a, int b) { return a % 2 == 0; }

does not respect the requirements of strict weak ordering which is required for using std::sort.
The requirements for strict weak ordering are:


it is irreflexive: for all x, r(x, x) is false;
it is transitive: for all a, b and c, if r(a, b) and r(b, c) are both true then r(a, c) is true;
let e(a, b) be !r(a, b) && !r(b, a), then e is transitive: e(a, b) && e(b, c) implies e(a, c).


But cmp(x,x) will return true for any even number x (e.g.: cmp(4,4)), violating the first requirement  (irreflexivity).
The result of using such a comparator is undefined behavior, which mean anything can happen (heap-buffer-overflow included).
The second comparator does not violate the requirements and is therefore OK.
